# Rpy2 works only from console

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've installed `rpy2` via `conda install -c r rpy2`. 
After this, I tried to execute `import rpy2.robjects as robjects` in my jupyter notebook and kernel died and restarted. 
But when i run this import from console, it works well, without any errors. 
How to fix this?